# Is Firebase Authentication available for blazor?

Tags: firebase-authentication, blazor

Is there a way to use Firebase Authentication in Blazor platform? 
I found ways to use facebook and google authentication natively, but I save the firebase user id in my database and I would like to use firebase authentication for this particular reason.

Comment: So you want us to solve your problem without showing what you have tried? I think this wont work unfortunately.

Comment: @Marc did you read what I wrote? I am searching a way to use firebase authentication on blazor. Google doesn't have anything about it...
[Facebook Authentication](https://ankitsharmablogs.com/facebook-authentication-and-authorization-in-server-side-blazor-app/)
[Google Authentication](https://ankitsharmablogs.com/google-authentication-and-authorization-in-server-side-blazor-app/)

Comment: Is your goal to authenticate users you setup in firebase or use firebase as realtime database without user ?

Comment: I created a web api that registers a user in Firebase Authentication and I pass those values to an sql server (except password). So my goal is indeed to authenticate users from firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase use **OAuth2** you need a Service account and the its private key file.
You can use [Google.Apis.Auth](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client). Not sure it work on client-side.

You can take a look at https://github.com/aguacongas/Identity.Firebase/tree/master/src/Aguacongas.Firebase.Authentication to have a sample in .Net.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it and post my results.

Comment: @ITBoxDeveloper how are your results?